# How to upgrade angularjs module to inject in angular2 component

Tags: angularjs, angular

I read the [Angular 2 upgrade guide](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/upgrade.html) and successfully bootstrapped a hybrid app (ng1 as base code and now incrementally rewriting the components and services to ng2).
Now what I don't understand is how I can use 3rd party ng1 modules, let angular2 inject them into my HeaderComponent?
I just saw examples of upgrading providers and components, but I think I'm still confused abou the module concept in angular2 so I don't get how to upgrade **ng1 modules**. Someone can please enlighten me?

**upgrade_adapter.ts**

```
import {AppModule} from './app.module';
import {UpgradeAdapter} from '@angular/upgrade';

export const upgradeAdapter = new UpgradeAdapter(AppModule);
```

**app.module.ts**

```
// imports...
@NgModule({
    imports: [ 
        BrowserModule, 
        HttpModule 
    ],
    declarations: [ 
        HeaderComponent 
    ],
    providers: [ MyService ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

**index.ts**

```
import { upgradeAdapter } from './upgrade_adapter';
// more imports...

angular.module(MODULE_NAME, [
    //...
])

// HeaderComponent uses a ng1 3rd party module, how to use that module in that component
.component('header', upgradeAdapter.downgradeNg2Component(HeaderComponent))

// adding some ng1 components...

.factory('myService', upgradeAdapter.downgradeNg2Provider(MyService));

// bootstrap the application
angular.element(document).ready(function () {
    upgradeAdapter.bootstrap(document.body, [MODULE_NAME]);
});
```

**EDIT:**
The 3rd party module is written in JS.

**lib/angular-modules/communication/index.js**

```
var communicationModule = angular.module('communication', [])
    .factory('communication', require('./communication.factory'));
module.exports = communicationModule.name;
```

Answer (score 1):

So I had a similar problem, basically I want to declare ng1 components in child modules. The only way I've found to do it is to use a dummy class to build the upgradeAdapter then switch it out just before calling the bootstrap method. You'll need to create new modules for Angular 2 and declare the ng1 components in them.

Hope this helps, took me ages to work out.

**upgrade_adapter.ts**

```
import {UpgradeAdapter} from '@angular/upgrade';
import { NgModule, forwardRef } from '@angular/core';

export const upgradeAdapter = new UpgradeAdapter(forwardRef(() => DummyClass)
@NgModule({})
export class DummyClass { }
```

**app.module.ts**

```
import { Ng1Module } from 'ng1.module';
// imports...
@NgModule({
    imports: [ 
        BrowserModule, 
        HttpModule,
        Ng1Module
    ],
    declarations: [ 
        HeaderComponent 
    ],
    providers: [ MyService ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

**ng1.module.ts**

```
import { upgradeAdapter } from './upgrade-adapter'

@NgModule( {
    declarations:[upgradeAdapter.upgradeNg1Component('ng1Component'),]
})
export class Ng1Module {}
```

**index.ts**

```
import { upgradeAdapter } from './upgrade-adapter'
import { AppModule} from './app.module'

/** codes **/

angular.element(document).ready(function () {
    upgradeAdapter['ng2AppModule'] = AppModule;
    upgradeAdapter.bootstrap(document.body, ['app']);
});
```

Comment: This doesn't work in my case as I want to upgrade a whole ng1 **module**, which itself contains serveral factories and requires some other 3rd party libs (e.g. angular-translate). So as there is no _upgradeAdapter.upgradeNg1Module_ or something, I guess there is no way of reusing my existing ng1 module.

Comment: Not that I've seen, as I understand it you'd have to essentially declare the module in ng2 and redeclare all the services and components. This should still work for 3rd party libs.